# Error at converting PHP string in HTML code

Tags: php, html

I have this `PHP` code:

```
$htmlCode = '
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
                </form>
            ';
```

And I want to put it in a part of my `HTML` using this:

```
<html>
   <?php
       echo $htmlCode;
   ?>
</html>
```

But when I open the file it shows this:
[image]

And I don't know why. Please help

Comment: Don't `<?php echo ...` _inside_ of PHP. In fact, your `action` can just be `action=""` to post the form to the same page

Comment: You can also completely omit the `action` attribute to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP-Code should look like:

```
<?php
$htmlCode = '
            <form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'"     method="post">
            </form>
        ';
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

this is big mistake

try this code

```php
<?php

$path = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
$htmlCode = "<form action='{$path}' method='post'></form>";
echo $htmlCode;
```

even you don't need `$path`
this is also work

```php
<?php
$htmlCode = '<form action"" method="post"></form>';
echo $htmlCode;

?>
```

Comment: You don't even need to echo the `$htmlCode`. Just add the `<form>` tag into the HTML body. No PHP is required.